# How to solder on a new USB plug/connector

Tags: usb, soldering

I bought a USB WiFi card, but then the metal part broke and I had to take it off. I only have the board now and it is too small to fit into a USB port. Where can I find a new USB head/plug (the silver part used to plug it into the USB ports, sorry I cannot find a name anywhere). And how would I go about soldering on this new head?

Refer to the picture of the memory stick if you do not understand what I mean with the silver part

[image: wireless card right]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you should re-use the part that broke off.  But you likely don't actually need it, you can just shim the back of the board with plastic to make it fit.  If you soldered on a conventional USB plug it would probably quickly break off, likely ripping the traces with it and completely ruining the device.

Comment: I think the part you want it's called a shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metal part of a USB plug is always the same size. You can probably buy a plug that has the metal part the right length remove the contacts, and the plastic that carries the contacts and glue your circuit board inside  you need to keep the metal away from the antenna at the back end of that circuit.

I found the exact part you want, but you need to buy 500 and they are sold out. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/usb-shell/1526455799.html

next best is a stubby plug like 
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10-Pcs-USB-A-Male/32945199926.html
and remove the white part by force

Answer (score 1):

Get a short USB extender and plug the module into the end and cover with heatshrink tubing [image]

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to do any soldering most likely. You'll need to find a suitable USB shell - say from an old thumb drive - as long as the main body is plastic.  Opene it up (it might only be snapped together if you are lucky) and remove the internals and replace with your board.  It's possible it'll just snap into place - again, if you're lucky.